# Frequency of letters: "array initializer must be an initializer list or string literal" error

Tags: c++

I am writting a program that will output the frequency of letters from a string.
When I try to output it, I get the error "array initializer must be an initializer list or string literal". I was wondering how I would be able to use an user input instead of having a set string like char str[100] = "hello";

This is what I have tried

```
            char letters;

            cout<<"Please enter a list of letters: ";
            cin>>letters;


            char str[100] = letters;
            int i;
            int freq[256] = {0};

            //Calculating frequency of each character.
            for(i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++)
            {
                freq[str[i]]++;
            }

            //Printing frequency of each character.
            for(i = 0; i < 256; i++)
            {
                if(freq[i] != 0)
                {
                   cout<<char(i)<<" : "<<freq[i]<<endl;
                }
            }
```

however, it does not allow me to user an user input equal to char str[100]

Is there a way for me to use an user imput?

Comment: Why use char arrays in C++ at all?

Comment: `char letters;` allocates space for a single `char`. You can't `cin` a string or list into a single character. You have other errors in your code as well.